# How to deal with faulted objects returned by fetchedResultsController when the returned object may also be deleted from the persistent store

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

1. In my simple experiments it doesn't seem that the fetchedResultsController is returning faulted objects. Is it possible for the fetchedResultsController to return a faulted Core Data object for a specific index path?
2. The sample code below runs on the main thread. Lets say that at "Point A" a background thread deletes and saves to the persistent store the object that was just returned by the fetched results controller. Now when we attempt to access properties on the `dataObject` we crash because the fault cannot be fulfilled since the data has been deleted from the persistent store.
3. One thing I have seen is that the relationships are more likely to be faulted. So instead at "Point A" lets say that the parent object is deleted from the persistent store. Then when attempting to access the name property on the parent an error will occur since a fault cannot be fulfilled.
4. What is the best way to prevent this sort of problem?

Sample code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = code_for_cell_reuse_here;

    PersonModelObject *dataObject = (PersonModelObject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        /* Point A */

    cell.textLabel.text = dataObject.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dataObject.parent.name;

    return cell; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification from the other thread and refresh your context.

This can be done synchronously, avoiding the race condition by blocking on the main thread update using performSelectorOnMainThread or using a block.

You can then either manually, or using refreshFromContextDidSaveNotification:mergeChanges: update your local managed object context, but if the volume of data is sufficiently large it might be easiest to just call -reset on the managed object context and -performFetch on the fetched results controller.

Comment: If handling NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification is done correctly is it guaranteed that the object returned by the NSFetchedResultsController will not be a fault?

Comment: No, the only way to guarantee that the fetched results controller won't return a fault is to set -returnsObjectsAsFaults to NO. As another answer stated below you can also use relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching to indicate that certain relationships should be fetched instead of faulted.

Answer (score 1):

To answer another aspect of your question (hopefully more usefully), `NSFetchedResultsController` should return faulted objects (i.e. attributes already loaded), and you can use `NSFetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` to pre-fault relationships.

Answer (score 0):

`-[NSManagedObject isDeleted]`

Comment: The race condition still exists even with this check. Specifically when the dataObject is deleted after the isDeleted check and before faulted properties are accessed.

Comment: True. You could use a lock, or change to a different store/context configuration. In iOS 5 and Lion, you can use nested contexts for this.